# better way of this query in django

Tags: django, django-queryset

I am trying to get all news of some certain channels:

```
news = []
channels_in_these_languages = Channel.objects.filter(channel_lang__in=langs)
for each_channel in channels_in_these_languages: 
   news.append(each_channel.channel_news.all())
```

`channel_news` is the `related_name` of news table for of each channel.

But, looping over channels and appending each channel news into a list seems to be ugly to me. is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: If you want 'news' start from news: `News.objects.filter(channel__channel_lang__in=langs)` (I can only guess your models structure)